# C++ output based on two different inputs

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I've looked on other websites but can't find anything that works for me.

I'm trying of add discounts on furniture sales based on the item ordered and the amount of that item ordered, find the table below:

table (0):
Amount ordered (discount offered): 1-5(5%), 6-9(10%), 10+(20%)

chair(1)
Amount ordered (discount offered): 1-5(3%), 6-9(7%), 10+(12%)

Here's my code, I still can't get it to work as this is my second week using the C++ programming language. I would appreciate it if someone could please let me know what it is that I'm doing wrong:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main ()

{
 int yc;
 char cc;

 cout <<"Enter furniture code:";
 cin >> yc;

 cout <<"Enter amount ordered:";
 cin >> cc;

 switch (yc)
 {
 case 0: cout <<"you selected item: " << yc << endl;
        break;
 case 1: cout <<"you selected item: " << yc << endl;
        break;

 }

 switch (cc)
 {

        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':



        cout <<"discount applied: " << cc << endl;
                     break;

        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
        case '9':


        cout <<"discount applied: " << cc << endl;
                     break;

        default:
            if (cc >= 10)
                cout <<" discount applied: " << cc << endl;

 }

 system("PAUSE");
 return 0;
}
```

If my inputs are:

```
Enter furniture code: 0
Enter amount ordered: 4
```

It outputs:

```
you selected item: 0
discount applied: 4
```

I want to output to be:

```
you selected item: 0
```

discount applied: 5%

since I seelected the table (0) and the amount ordered is between 1-5.

Comment: can you explain what the current output is, and what is should be?

Comment: I agree with @Wimmel the question is unclear.

Comment: I edited the question. Hopes it's clear this time.

Comment: The problem is that it is open-ended. You are asking for mentoring or debugging assistance, but that can be provided on a message board or chatroom, not a Q&A repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You print `cc` but it is not the discount, it is the amount of ordered. Instead you need to print the discount:

```
cout <<"discount applied: 5%" << endl;
```

Also, you should consider using if/else statement instead of switch/case.
For example:

```
if(cc <= 5)
    cout <<"discount applied: 5%" << endl;
else if(cc <= 10)
    cout <<"discount applied: 10%" << endl;
else
    cout <<"discount applied: 20%" << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks,this looks much easier. How do I show to the discount based on furniture selected?

Comment: You can just use an other if/else statement to check whether yc is equal to 0 (table) or 1 (chair).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this:

```
 switch (yc)
 {
 case 0: cout <<"you selected item: " << yc << endl;
        break;
 case 1: cout <<"you selected item: " << yc << endl;
        break;

 }
```

Is not necessary, since both cases output the same thing. Just replace that with this:

```
cout <<"you selected item: " << yc << endl;
```

Second, you should use a series of if-else statements, considering how few cases you have:

```
if (yc == 0) {
    if (cc <= 5) {
        cout << "Discount applied: 5%" << endl;
    }
    else if (cc < 10) {
        // discount = 10%
    } 
    // etc...
}

if (yc == 1) {
    if (cc <= 5) {
        // etc...
```

Comment: This sounds like an answer for something on codereview, not something on stackoverflow. This doesn't fix the problem too.

Comment: His problem was that he couldn't get the current discount based on the number of certain items bought. This fixes this. @Chantola